# Not sure why my function is is causing a compiler error when all components have been defined

Tags: c++, class, pointers, linked-list

I am making a linked list, and my function to insert something at the front of my list is causing a compiler error I am not sure why because all of the variables I am using in my function are defined.

For context, the following code is to sort an input such as

```
4
plates 100
spoons 200
cups 150
forks 200
```

InventoryNode.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class InventoryNode {
private:
    string item;
    int numberOfItems;
    InventoryNode *nextNodeRef;
    string next;

public:
    //Constructor
    InventoryNode() {
        this->item = "";
        this->numberOfItems = 0;
        this->nextNodeRef = NULL;
    }

    //Constructor
    InventoryNode(string itemInit, int numberOfItemsInit) {
        this->item = itemInit;
        this->numberOfItems = numberOfItemsInit;
        this->nextNodeRef = NULL;
    }

    //Constructor
    InventoryNode(string itemInit, int numberOfItemsInit, InventoryNode nextLoc) {
        this->item = itemInit;
        this->numberOfItems = numberOfItemsInit;
        this->nextNodeRef = &nextLoc;
    }


    void InsertAtFront(InventoryNode* head, InventoryNode* currNode) {
          currNode->head;
          head = currNode;
    }


    //Get the next node
    InventoryNode *GetNext() {
        return this->nextNodeRef;
    }

    //Print node data
    void PrintNodeData() {
        cout << this->numberOfItems << " " << this->item << endl;
    }
};
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "InventoryNode.h"

int main() {
    int count;
    int numItems;
    string item;

    InventoryNode *headNode = new InventoryNode();
    InventoryNode *currNode;

    // Obtain number of items
    cin >> count;

    // Get each item and number of each
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        cin >> item;
        cin >> numItems;
        currNode = new InventoryNode(item, numItems);
        currNode->InsertAtFront(headNode, currNode);
    }

    // Print linked list
    currNode = headNode->GetNext();
    while (currNode != NULL) {
        currNode->PrintNodeData();
        currNode = currNode->GetNext();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you so much for any help :)

Comment: Please always verbatim copy-paste the full error message into the question.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::sort` and `vector< pair<int, string> >` or `list< pair<int, string> >` if you're keen on using a linked list?

Comment: Fyi, `head = currNode;` means nothing to the caller (`main`) of `InsertAtFront`. That is a by-value parameter. `head` is not updated outside of the function with that call. There are at least a thousand duplicates of that issue on SO, but the mistake is frequently made by starting programmers, and the choices of vernacular (besides it-don't-work, which isn't helpful at all) and code are so divergent it is harder to find those duplicates than one may at-first think.

Comment: `<source>:35:21: error: 'class InventoryNode' has no member named 'head'`: Seems pretty obvious what the problem is.

Comment: Neither line in `InsertAtFront()` make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

> currNode->head;

Code you provided has no `head` field.